# Is PHP uniqid safe for HTML id attribute?

Tags: php, html, w3c-validation

I'd like to use a random `id` attribute in HTML:

```
<?php $id = uniqid(); ?>
<div data-cycle-prev="#<?php echo $id; ?>_slideshow_prev">
    <div id="<?php echo $id; ?>_slideshow_prev"></div>
</div>
```

I'm using PHP method `uniqid` to generate it, but I don't know if it is safe and W3C compliant?

My concern for compliance is for the generated HTML which the PHP outputs. Not all characters are allowed in an HTML attribute, so I was wondering if `uniqid()` generates only allowed characters.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with using this. The only security-related issue would be if you don't want someone/or bot to figure out what the random chars. have generated or are trying to protect a document. Far as I know, PHP has nothing to do with being W3C compliant; HTML, yes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My concern for compliance was for the generated html php outputs. Not all characters are allowed in an html attribute, so I was wondering if uniqid() generates only allowed characters.

Comment: You're welcome. Have a look at the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: What is the reason you need an id there?

Comment: I need it for jquery cycle2 plugin. I want multiple slideshows on a page, and still be able to assign ids to controls (the data-cycle-prev attribute corresponds to a dom element, which I can then place anywhere I want).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uniqid` returns id, which contains hexadecimal symbols(0-9, a-f). This is explained in manual comments - http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php#95001

So, yes, this is safe for html attributes.

Comment: If you pass true in the $more_entropy argument, it will also include periods. In that case it's not safe for an ID attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is save, as long you do not generate the id twice times, which is very unlikly.

I would do it another way. Maybe you want to introduce this in to your library

```
function getNextInt() {
    static $i = 0;
    $i++;
    return $i;
}
```

And in Your Template:

```
<?php $id = getNextInt(); ?>
<div data-cycle-prev="#<?php echo $id; ?>_slideshow_prev">
    <div id="<?php echo $id; ?>_slideshow_prev"></div>
</div>
```

If you are using older Versions of HTML, we need to have a letter first as id (statet from @mb21 in the comments):

```
<?php $id = 'mycontrol' . getNextInt(); ?>
```

Comment: Note that in HTML 4 and earlier, `id`s must start with a letter.

Comment: No, it is not a hack. It is a language feature, not limited to only PHP. Static means, the variable is intialized on first call, but on next call, it is availible, with the last value.